# Authorize.Net: "Unexpected Error" while using invoiceNumber

Tags: authorize.net

I am trying to send the `invoiceNumber` and `description` in my request to Authorize.Net server, but get an `"Unexpected error. Please try again."` message.

If I comment out the code below which adds the `invoiceNumber` and `description`, it works each time.

```
transactionRequest.order = new orderType
{
    invoiceNumber = "2585",
    description = "Permit Application Fees: PRSF201900114",
};
```

Here is the data that I am sending to Authorize.Net while fetching the token:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<getHostedPaymentPageRequest
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <merchantAuthentication>
        <name></name>
        <transactionKey></transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
    <clientId>sdk-dotnet-2.0.1</clientId>
    <transactionRequest>
        <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
        <amount>338.78</amount>
        <order>
            <invoiceNumber>2585</invoiceNumber>
            <description>Permit Application Fees: PRSF201900114</description>
        </order>
        <lineItems>
            <lineItem>
                <itemId>9795</itemId>
                <name>W028</name>
                <description>Building Permit Fee</description>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <unitPrice>23.50</unitPrice>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <itemId>9797</itemId>
                <name>E002</name>
                <description>Ele: Electrical Service New/Al</description>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <unitPrice>100.00</unitPrice>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <itemId>9798</itemId>
                <name>W061</name>
                <description>Gas: Grain bin &gt; 400,000 Btu's</description>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <unitPrice>100.00</unitPrice>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <itemId>9799</itemId>
                <name>W45</name>
                <description>Mechanical Permit Fee</description>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <unitPrice>100.00</unitPrice>
            </lineItem>
            <lineItem>
                <itemId>9800</itemId>
                <name>W034</name>
                <description>Plan Check Fee</description>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
                <unitPrice>15.28</unitPrice>
            </lineItem>
        </lineItems>
        <customer>
            <type>individual</type>
            <email>testUser@test.com</email>
        </customer>
    </transactionRequest>
    <hostedPaymentSettings>
        <setting>
            <settingName>hostedPaymentButtonOptions</settingName>
            <settingValue>{"text": "Pay"}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
            <settingName>hostedPaymentOrderOptions</settingName>
            <settingValue>{"show": false}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
            <settingName>hostedPaymentReturnOptions</settingName>
            <settingValue>{"showReceipt" : false, "cancelUrl": "https://localhost:44300/Payment/RedirectHandler"}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
            <settingName>hostedPaymentPaymentOptions</settingName>
            <settingValue>{"showBankAccount": true}</settingValue>
        </setting>
        <setting>
            <settingName>hostedPaymentIFrameCommunicatorUrl</settingName>
            <settingValue>{"url": "https://localhost:44300/Payment/IFrameCommunicator"}</settingValue>
        </setting>
    </hostedPaymentSettings>
</getHostedPaymentPageRequest>
```

What am I missing?

**Note: I came across similar question [here](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Accept-Hosted-transactionRequestType-Order-causes-Unexpected/td-p/66972) and [here](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/OrderType-is-causing-Unexpected-error-during-Payment-withour/td-p/65309) on Authorize.Net support but it seems to be an unresolved issue.**

Comment: What version of the Authorize.net SDK are you using? Also, are you using he correct  merchant account per environment (i.e. Sanbox / Production)?

Comment: I am using `sdk-dotnet-2.0.1`, with the correct account. It works perfectly fine if I don't include the `invoiceNumber` and `description`.

Comment: I recall they had a rather small max character length for description field. Try shortening it and see if transaction is successful.

Comment: I tried a small string (5 characters) as well as an empty string. Didn't work, still getting "Unexpected Error".

Answer (score 0):

We already found the solution.

In the orderType Class, there was a purchaseOrderDateUTC property which was set as required.
**Solution:**
Delete purchaseOrderDateUTC property under "Utility/AnetApiSchema.generated.cs"